# Why tools like afterburner, wattool, need us to disable motherboard GPU?

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, motherboard, hdmi, gpu

I have a motherboard with 6 GPU (for mining)

To make sure that the computer always boot even though the GPU have wrong bios or whatever, I simply connect the screen to motherboard HDMI. Even that is temporary solution. I expect my computer or mining rig to run without monitor most of the time and that I would access the computer via remote desktop.

So not only none of the GPU is connected to any monitor, I expect nothing will be connected to monitor. The GPU is for mining only and not for display. And I access the computer via remote desktop anyway.

My problem is, most tools, like watttool and afterburner cannot access the GPU.

[image]

[image]

Some says that I need to plug hdmi or dummy plug to one of the GPU and things would work. A few people have said that and they are familiar with multi GPU motherboard. They're miners too.

> Disable onboard and connect a monitor to gpu or connect a dummy plug
>   to the card hdmi then problem solved like magic Smiley , no way to
>   read card data without a monitor or dummy plug connected to gpu.

https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=1849865.new#new

I bet it's true.

That being said, I want to know why it's true and if it is at all.

Comment: So why are you trying to disable the onboard GPU? Will your computer not boot if there is no display connected? There is usually a setting in the BIOS to allow headless booting, if that's what you're looking for. Disabling the iGPU should not be necessary.

Comment: I was told to disable the onboard GPU so that watttool and afterburner can read my card data. You can check on the link I gave you.

Comment: So connect a screen to whatever graphics card you’re working on.

Comment: Your question is flawed.  I can run the same version of Afterburner your using, with my iGPU enabled, and it will function exactly like it should.  As for the reason, the software requires the GPU to be connected to something, that would be a question to the author of Afterburner.  You do understand that, once the GPU has been overclocked, it shouldn't be necessary to use Afterburner again.  You can also just overclocked, the GPU, within your miner software.

Comment: You can? The software requires the GPU to be connected to something. Why? Also afterburner is not the only thing that fail. Sapphire Tripp and watttool also fails. Are you using asrock BTC as well?

Comment: Are you using mining rig?

Comment: What’s the motherboard are you using? I am looking for a ATX motherboard to build a GPU miner.

Answer (score 1):

if you are minning you dont need any dummy adapters or anything else. I had the same problem and I have realized that the Problem is RDP or any other remote desktop tool. when you want to connect remotely to that computer, it tries to give you the best resolution and it couldnt find one because no monitor is attached so therefore Mining will not work at the time you are logged in through any Remote desktop tool. the solution is just close all remote desktop tool and it will work again with normal Hash powers..